# Linux Systemd conflicts doesn't seem to use ExecStopPost

Tags: systemd

**A.service**

```
[Unit]
Description = A-service
Conflicts= B.service
After = network.target

[Service]
PermissionsStartOnly = true
PIDFile = /run/AB/ab.pid
User = root
WorkingDirectory = /root/AB_services
ExecStartPre = /bin/mkdir /run/AB
ExecStartPre = /bin/chown -R root:root /run/AB
ExecStart = /usr/bin/python test_A.py --pid /run/AB/ab.pid
ExecReload = /bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
ExecStop = /bin/kill -s TERM $MAINPID
ExecStopPost = /bin/rm -rf /run/AB
PrivateTmp = true

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

**B.service**

```
[Unit]
Description = B-Service
Conflicts = A.service
After = network.target

[Service]
PermissionsStartOnly = true
PIDFile = /run/AB/ab.pid
User = root
WorkingDirectory = /root/AB_services
ExecStartPre = /bin/mkdir /run/AB
ExecStartPre = /bin/chown -R root:root /run/AB
ExecStart = /usr/bin/python test_B.py --pid /run/AB/ab.pid
ExecReload = /bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
ExecStop = /bin/kill -s TERM $MAINPID
ExecStopPost = /bin/rm -rf /run/AB
PrivateTmp = true

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

I initially started the `A.service` and it started successfully. However, when I start `B.service`, I see the `A.service` is ending. But its `ExecStopPost` doesn't seem to execute as I am getting the following error :

```
/bin/mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/run/AB’: File exists
```

Does `ExecStopPost` really not work with `Conflicts`??

Thank you.

Comment: The `/run/AB/ab.pid` file is being used by `B.service`. Even though `Conflicts` works and stops `A.service`, it can't delete a file currently being used by another service. So its `ExecStopPost` will fail.

Comment: Creating seperate run directories for both the services worked. Thank you.

Comment: @RatDon this is incorrect. `rm` is happy to delete the files no matter what service uses them.

Comment: @Patrick Thanks for clearing my doubt. It was there from a long time and I got it confused with windows. :D

Answer (score 2):

You have not specified any ordering constraints between the two services. Thus what is happening is that `B.service` is starting (and executing the `mkdir`) before `A.service` has finished stopping (and executed the `rm`).
The relevant section of the [systemd.unit docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Conflicts=):

> Conflicts=
>   Note that this setting is independent of and orthogonal to the After= and Before= ordering dependencies.

The solution is to add the other service to each's `After=` list (add `A.service` to `B.service`'s `After=` and vice versa).
See also this relevant section of [the docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Before=):

> Before=, After=
>   Given two units with any ordering dependency between them, if one unit is shut down and the other is started up, the shutdown is ordered before the start-up. It doesn't matter if the ordering dependency is After= or Before=, in this case. It also doesn't matter which of the two is shut down, as long as one is shut down and the other is started up. The shutdown is ordered before the start-up in all cases.

^ meaning it really doesn't matter if you use `After=` or `Before=`. They'll both accomplish the same thing.

Comment: In my case, the ordering of the services is not specified. Hence I want only one service to be up at any moment.

Comment: I found that you have to add After= to just one of the services.  If you add it to both, it gives an error that "Transaction order is cyclic."

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [Patrick](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4358/patrick) for such an explained answer and clearing some of my doubts.

Thanks [wonder](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/276924/wonder) for doing the testings on behalf of me.

As [Patrick](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4358/patrick)'s answer mentions, because of the undefined order, it may misbehave. `B.service` can't run the `mkdir` as the directory already exists and `A.service` has not removed it yet.

1. You can define an order for both of them. Doesn't matter which starts first, they will behave the same as per your current requirement.
2. Or you can create separate `pid` files for both the services and under `ExecStopPost` just remove the `pid` file instead of the directory.

Keep in mind, if you are following the second method, `ExecStartPre` won't be required.

FYI, after going through some of the `init.d` scripts, I think the best place to put the `pid` files is `/var/run/` without creating any extra directory. **This will be valid only if your services are started as root as the location is write protected for root only.**